# What parts to really keep out of antennas keep-out box, and which not so much?

Tags: rf, antenna, surface-mount

I'm in the process of designing a pcb for a very small IoT device and need to get it as compact as possible. I'm currently considering these two smd antennas:

https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/as/AS-47948-001-001.pdf
[image]

http://www.proant.se/files/user/Documents/Datasheets%20and%20appnotes/Upload%202018-06-08/Application%20note%20-%20OnBoard%20SMD%202400%20MHz%20rev%203.2.pdf
[image]

The second one is significantly larger, but it elevates the actual antenna away from the board and the documentation states that it might be ok to place smd components inside the block.

The first one is smaller, but the sheet shows that efficiency drops quite significantly when big metal parts are placed closer than 5mm to it.

I wonder, if I do have to place smd parts close to the antenna due to size requirements, which parts should I prefer to place there?

Comment: Unless you feel like using RF modeling software, keepout means *everything*.  Not just parts, but traces too.

Comment: Anyone browsing your question has to follow two links just to understand it. Why not upload the images into your question? You'll get much more interest and, perhaps, better responses.

Comment: Since the larger antenna requires the ground plane on the top layer, are you able to place components on the opposite side of the board under the antenna as to not interfere with the ground plane?  Any deviation from the optimal design will reduce performance of the part and will certainly require tuning in circuit.

Comment: @BEE, that's what I don't know - can I place parts underneath on the bottom side? I have to deviate from the optimal design anyway due to space limitations. Question is how I reduce the performance the least.

Comment: "**need** to get it as compact as **possible**" - I wouldn't use either of them because it must be possible to make a smaller one (and since you need the smallest _possible_...).

Answer (score 0):

Anything conductive:  wires, traces, resistors, metal hardware, conductive liquids, etc.

Plastic, wood, and other dielectrics will have a small effect but probably not enough to worry about.

Comment: So it's not like a resistor would be less detrimental than a capacitor or a coil for example?

Comment: mist resistors have metal end caps,  but even without that aresistor would absorb energy so you'll lose either way attenuated by a the resistive part or de-tuned by the conductive part.  if you were to pass the glass part of a gigahohm resistor through the keep out the radio would probably work fine, but you may find that it disturbs your measurements that use the resistor. the ceramic bodies of power resitors are probably OK if they have a reasonably high resistance,  but be aware that there are metal caps at each end.

Comment: so it really is just the metal that is the problem and electromagnetic fields the components may generate are irrelevant?

Comment: yes, but remember that most components contain a lot of metal.